# How to run angular build under golang revel framework

Tags: go, revel

I have one angular build files in public folder in revel appplication. 
I want to run those html and js files under revel application.

```
GET     /   Static.Serve("public")
```

I gave the above code in routes file. When I try in browser, it's showing "Forbidden
Directory listing not allowed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these two line in routes file. Here all GET request will move to app controller Index function.

```
GET     /                                       App.Index
GET     /*                                      App.Index
```

add below code in app controller file.

```
func (c App) Index() revel.Result {
    dir, doc := path.Split(c.Request.URL.Path)
    ext := filepath.Ext(doc)
    if doc == "" || ext == "" {
        return c.RenderFileName("./public/index.html", "inline")
    } else {
        if _, err := os.Stat("./public/" + path.Join(dir, doc)); err != nil {
            return c.RenderFileName("./public/index.html", "inline")
        }
        return c.RenderFileName("./public/" + path.Join(dir, doc), "inline")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not big deal, you were close

```
GET         /                       Static.Serve("public/index.html")
```

Then your angulars should do his works.

Comment: GET / Static.Serve("public/index.html") I gave like this. Then It will load all html files. But If I refresh browser, it's showing error "File not found"

Comment: To be fair, myself I won't put angular-cli inside your golang project.

if you can is better to have two project

backend and another one for frontend
later on NGinx for example
backend    /api
frontend      /*


Then you can easaly solve future issues you will have by mixing both

Now if you keep frontend to your golang project you have issues,
because your angular-cli routeur will catch request before Revel